# Image not load with link_to image_tag on Rails 4.2.5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, svg

I pass 2 hours on a problem & I didn't find any answer.. In simply add a link with an image tag on Ruby on Rails like that

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("/assets/images/icons/facebook.svg"),'https://www.facebook.com/raspberrycook')%>
```

and the picture doesn't appear. I check with Firefox's debugger and image won't load. But when I try to get *http://localhost:3000/assets/images/icons/facebook.svg*, image appear! So I rename the picture as *fb.svg* & I update my link...

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("/assets/images/icons/fb.svg"),'https://www.facebook.com/raspberrycook')%>
```

... and it works! Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are using assets pipeline correctly?

Comment: because if you are then you can simply put images/icons/faceboo.svg

Comment: You really don't want to set a path as a parameter with image_tag, just use the filename like: `image_tag("facebook.svg")`

Comment: I already founded a solution. My question was "**Why** my last code didn't work?"